# How can a filter out the array entries?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

How can a filter out the array entries

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => A
    [2] => A
    [3] => B
    [4] => A
    [5] => B
)
etc....
```

i would like to get this result

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => A
        [3] => B
    )
```

i need to remove duplicate secquence

Comment: Have you tried something to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this as a human, the process is easy:

- Look at current value.
- Check the last value.
- Remove it if they match.

The process using code is the same:

```
//the initial data
$test = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B"];

//remember the last value
$last = null;

foreach($test as $key => $value){
    //is there a last value? does it match the current value?
    if($last AND $last == $value){
        //then remove it
        unset($test[$key]);
        continue;
    }

   //remember the last value
    $last = $value;
}

var_dump($test);
```

The output:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "A"
  [3] =>
  string(1) "B"
  [4] =>
  string(1) "A"
  [5] =>
  string(1) "B"
}
```

And as [Mark points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35816103/45531) you can use `array_filter()` to do the same thing.

In that case you just need to declare the `$last` variable [as `static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static), since you only want it to be `null` the first time the function is called, and you want it to keep its value over multiple calls to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple using [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and just comparing each value with the previous one

```
$data = ['A','A','A','B','A','B'];

$data = array_filter(
    $data,
    function($value) {
        static $previous = null;
        $return = $value != $previous;
        $previous = $value;
        return $return;
    }
);

var_dump($data);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/IdIP9)